# Specify equality with a lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, iequalitycomparer

I want to compare 2 collections. One of these is a `List<string>` and the other is a `List<Book>`. Book has a Isbn property of type `string`, and I want write something like that :

```
List<string> isbnBooks= new List<string> {"978-1933988276", "978-0321146533", "3"};
List<Book> books = new List<Book>();

books.Add(new Book { Isbn="978-1933988276", Name="The Art of Unit Testing"});
books.Add(new Book { Isbn="978-0321146533", Name="TDD By Example"});
books.Add(new Book { Isbn="978-0321503626", Name="Growing Object-Oriented Software"});

// What I want to write
var intersectedBooks = books.Intersect(books, isbnBooks, (book, isbn) => book.Isbn == isbn));
```

I would like specify equality in the method. Is it possible ? Or should I mandatory create a BookComparer which implements IEqualityComparer interface ?

Regards,

Florian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Intersect` simply doesn't work with different collection types. In this case it looks like it would be simpler to write:

```
HashSet<string> isbns = new HashSet<string> isbnBooks();   
var intersectedBooks = books.Where(book => isbns.Contains(book.Isbn));
```

Or you could just do a join, of course:

```
var knownBooks = from book in books
                 join isbn in isbnBooks on book.Isbn equals isbn
                 select book;
```

(The two approaches are broadly equivalent.)

Answer (score 2):

Or, you could always do:

```
var intersectedBooks = books.Select(book=>book.Isbn).Intersect(isbnBooks);
```

Comment: yes but returns IEnumerable<string> and I want Enumerable<Book>. Thank you for your answer !